# Tex symbols and package for falling factorial power. and other symbols

Tags: math-mode, symbols, packages

There are a lot of new type of symbols used in book: Concrete mathematics by Graham Knuth and Patashnik, I am trying to find many of these useful notations as latex symbols but failed. e.g Falling Factorial power which looks something like : [image]

I tried a combination of ^ and \uline but doesn't seem as good.

Also how to show some text on top like following :

[image]

Comment: This is an option: `\newcommand{\fallfac}[2]{{#1}^{\underline{#2}}}` or `$(n)_k$`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I see no real difficulty:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\fallingfactorial}[1]{%
  ^{\underline{#1}}%
}

\begin{document}

\[
x\fallingfactorial{n}={\overbrace{x(x-1)\dots(x-n+1)}^{\text{$n$ factors}}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

After adding

```
\usepackage[euler-digits]{eulervm}
```

you get

[image]

By the way, this is exactly how it's realized in `gkpmac.tex` (the macro file used for typesetting “Concrete Mathematics”).

```
\input gkpmac

$$
x\_{n}\qquad x\_^{n}
$$

\bye
```

[image]

The macros:

```
\def\_#1{\def\next{#1}%
 \ifx\next\risingsign\expandafter\rising\else^{\underline{#1}}\fi}
\def\risingsign{^}
\def\rising#1{^{\overline{#1}}}
```

A possible improvement:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[euler-digits]{eulervm}

\newcommand{\fallingfactorial}[1]{%
  ^{\mspace{2mu}\underline{\mspace{-2mu}#1\mspace{-2mu}}\mspace{2mu}}%
}
\newcommand{\raisingfactorial}[1]{%
  ^{\mspace{2mu}\overline{\mspace{-2mu}#1\mspace{-2mu}}\mspace{2mu}}%
}

\begin{document}

\[
x\fallingfactorial{n}={\overbrace{x(x-1)\dots(x-n+1)}^{\text{$n$ factors}}}
\]

\[
x\raisingfactorial{n}={\overbrace{x(x+1)\dots(x+n-1)}^{\text{$n$ factors}}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for prompt answer. I am getting started with Tex. And your answer has given useful hints and features I can grok upon.

Comment: +1 for the reference to gkpmac :-) It also has a `\hypstrut` which I assume would be used frequently in practice.